Can I make an AppIntent not show up in Siri suggestions?
I have an AppIntent that is only intended to be used as a shortcut assigned to the action button. Is it possible to prevent it from showing up as a suggestion in iOS search results?
AppIntent has an isDiscoverable property, but that looks like it would also prevent the intent from appearing in Shortcuts, and I need it to be available for assignment to the action button.
